# Could XmlSerializer and MemoryStream return an array of 0 value bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, file, xmlserializer, memorystream

I have a method that saves an instance of my custom class to a file. One time I noticed that my application fails to start, because this file is filled with 0-value bytes (null characters). This has never happened before, it seemed to work just fine. Does anyone see something odd with this code? Something that can cause the serializer or the memory stream to return an array of zero values? Or should I suspect it's the work of another application?

```
    private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));

    public void Save(MySettings config)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            _serializer.Serialize(stream, config);
            byte[] binaryConfig = stream.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes(_configFilePath, binaryConfig);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use something like this?

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(_configFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        x.Serialize(stream, config);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

The `XML` file should not contain any 0-bytes or `nul` characters, as your object is translated to `XML` text during serialization. You can simply open the `XML` file using a text editor to have a look at the file contents.